# How to enable the Single Instance Only option by default on IntelliJ run/debug configs?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

How to enable the Single Instance Only option by default on IntelliJ run/debug configs?

I run several Cucumber Java scenarios by right-click on the scenario on the editor and a new Run/Debug Config is created automatically. I would like to create these configs with the Single Instance Only enabled by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, I'm afraid. Please vote for the [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98563).

Comment: Thank you to provide the link to the feature request. I voted on it!

Comment: I think that you did a good found of the opened feature request. Enjoy your +100 :-)